# How can I use a nested CASE statement to check the values in 3 columns to set the value in a 4th column in Microsoft SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 columns that indicate if a company is active during the last 3 years (2021_active, 2020_active, 2019_active). I want to use a case statement to check if the company was active in 2020 or 2019, but is NOT active in 2021

```
ALTER Table [TMDB].[dbo].[2021 CCVL Draft] ADD Cancelled_CV varchar(10)



UPDATE [TMDB].[dbo].[2021 CCVL Draft]
    SET Cancelled_CV = CASE WHEN [TMDB].[dbo].[2021 CCVL Draft].[2021_Active] = 'N' THEN
                                CASE [TMDB].[dbo].[2021 CCVL Draft].[2019_Active] WHEN 'Y' THEN 'Y' ELSE                                    
                                        CASE [TMDB].[dbo].[2021 CCVL Draft].[2020_Active] WHEN 'Y' THEN 'Y' 
                                ELSE 'N' END
```

I'm getting an error  for the last line of the code: *Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'.*

The logic I want to implement is to first check to ensure 2021_active is N for No, and then, check if *either* 2019_active or 2020_active are yes.

Comment: Please explain the logic you want to implement.

Comment: Your table design looks to be denormalized. What will you do in 10 years time, have another 10 columns?

Comment: Stop writing code. You struggle because you are trying to both write code and understand your goal at the same time. Go create a truth table to help you visualize all the combinations of values for the three columns and what each combination should generate as a result. Once you do that, you will likely see exactly what your code should be. And stop using three part names - that's a bad habit. The current database of your connection should determine where your tables are located.

Answer (score 1):

You are nesting multiple `CASE` expressions but do not have enough `END`s.  Nesting `CASE` expressions is rarely needed.  I'm not sure what the exact logic you want is, but something like this:

```
UPDATE [TMDB].[dbo].[2021 CCVL Draft]
    SET Cancelled_CV = (CASE WHEN [TMDB].[dbo].[2021 CCVL Draft].[2021_Active] = 'N' AND
                                  [TMDB].[dbo].[2021 CCVL Draft].[2019_Active] = 'Y'
                             THEN 'Y'                                    
                             WHEN [TMDB].[dbo].[2021 CCVL Draft].[2020_Active] = 'Y' 
                             THEN 'Y' 
                             ELSE 'N'
                        END)
```

EDIT:

> The logic I want to implement is to first check to ensure 2021_active is N for No, and then, check if either 2019_active or 2020_active are yes.

For this logic, I think you want:

```
UPDATE [TMDB].[dbo].[2021 CCVL Draft]
    SET Cancelled_CV = (CASE WHEN [2021 CCVL Draft].[2021_Active] = 'N' AND
                                  ([2021 CCVL Draft].[2019_Active] = 'Y' OR
                                   [2021 CCVL Draft].[2020_Active] = 'Y'
                                  )
                             THEN 'Y'
                             ELSE 'N'
                        END)
```

Comment: @user18139 . . . This information belongs in the *question* not in a comment.  I updated the answer for that logic.

Comment: the second code block worked. It seems I just needed to use AND ( ...  or ...) for this